# What happens when a Red Hat Developer Subscription expires?

Tags: rhel, development, licenses

I have a Red Hat Developer Subscription which expires in January 2019. For now, I’m using RHEL for development purposes and it is free for me. What will happen after January 2019? Will my subscription no longer be free, or will my developer subscription be prolonged?

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When your current subscription expires, you’ll be able to [renew it at no cost](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/renew-your-red-hat-developer-program-subscription/), as long as you accept the terms and conditions again.